# Upgrade Fedora 13 to 15?

Tags: linux, upgrade, fedora

I have Fedora 13 64bit GNOME since one year and now I want upgrade to 15. Did any one encountered issues doing this type of upgrade? Should I first upgrade to 14 and then to 15?

Since I did yum update, I am being reminded that stable Fedora 14 is now available. This message pops up every day. Today I clicked on it and it is now giving me option to choose either Fedora 14 or Fedora 15.

Note that I am new to Linux and will not be able to fix something if something goes awry. I have a lot of programs pre-installed over the last one year and I simple cannot do a clean install. If something goes wrong does the upgrade offers a rollback feature like roll back to Fedora 13?

I would really like to take advantage of new features in Fedora 15.

Answer (score 2):

Fedora's **preupgrade** tool is the easiest way to upgrade from previous releases. That said, you should always backup important stuff before proceeding (there's no rollback feature).

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_use_PreUpgrade

Comment: Note that the recommended upgrade tool since Fedora 21 is [DNF system upgrade](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF_system_upgrade) plugin.